# I want to decrease the indent to checkboxes in exam class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

The indent to the checkbox is to big. I want it to be aligned with the first letter of the question.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{margin=1in} 
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\pointpoints{punt}{punten}
\pointsinmargin 
\boxedpoints
\begin{document}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\begin{questions}
\question[1] Een brekingsindex wordt uitgedrukt in
\begin{checkboxes}
\choice Graden
\choice Graden/meter
\CorrectChoice Heeft geen eenheid
\end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) provides a hook into the `checkboxes` environment called `\checkboxeshook`. This allows you to insert changes to the `checkboxes` environment just before the environment is called, without having to redefine the entire environment. Below I removed the `\labelsep` and `2.5em` horizontal skip that was added to the left margin, making it indent quite far. Perhaps this removal is sufficient:

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\pointpoints{punt}{punten}
\pointsinmargin 
\boxedpoints

\renewcommand{\checkboxeshook}{%
  \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.}% Included an additional \labelsep + 2.5em skip (now removed)
  \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep%
}

\begin{document}
\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\begin{questions}
  \question[1] Een brekingsindex wordt uitgedrukt in
  \begin{checkboxes}
    \choice Graden
    \choice Graden/meter
    \CorrectChoice Heeft geen eenheid
  \end{checkboxes}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```